# Issue with ranking Players in app in Java

Tags: java, android

I am trying to Rank players based on the number of wins they have.

Below is my code for the player results model:

```
public class PlayerResults implements Comparable<PlayerResults> {
    
    private String rank = "0";
    private String userName;
    private int wins;
    ...

    public int getPlayerWins() {

        return wins;                                 

    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(PickemResults another) {

        return wins.compareTo(another.wins);

    }

}
```

and below is the ranking for the players algo:

```
public static void standardRanking(List<PlayerResults> playerList) {

    for (int i = 0, rank = 0, group = 0; i < playerList.size(); i++) {

        if (group < playerList.size() && i == playerList.get(group).getPlayerWins()) {

            rank = i + 1;
            group++;

        }

        System.out.printf("%d %s%n", rank, playerList.get(i).getPlayerWins(),playerList.get(i).getPlayerUsername());

    }

}
```

This is the sort done prior to the ranking:

```
playerList.sort(Comparator.comparing(PlayerResults::getPlayerWins, Comparator.reverseOrder()));
```

Expected Result

```
1 44 Solomon
2 42 Jason
2 42 Errol
4 41 Garry
4 41 Bernard
4 41 Barry
7 39 Stephen
```

Can anyone see what I'm missing here!?

Comment: 1. Where is your `public int compareTo(PlayerResults pr)` method? 2. Where do you call `Collections.sort(...)` on your `List<PlayerResults>`? 3. Have you considered using a PriorityQueue?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels i have added it to the question

Comment: You did not answer question 2. You implemented `Comparable`, but you do not appear to be using it. "Can anyone see what I'm missing here!?" -- you are missing the input data and actual result, in addition to any programming problems.

Comment: Include a sample input that produces a list that is not in the order you expect and a complete enough code sample someone else could run it and see the same thing. We have no idea what list you are actually seeing, what your inputs are, or where it is you think you are sorting the list in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start by sorting the *playerList* by *wins*, in descending order.

Assign *i* to the rank, whenever the value decreases.

Here is an example.

```java
public static void standardRanking(List<PlayerResults> pr) {
    pr.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(x -> x.wins));
    Collections.reverse(pr);
    int i = 1, r = 1, pw = pr.get(0).wins;
    for (PlayerResults p : pr) {
        if (pw > p.wins) {
            r = i;
            pw = p.wins;
        }
        i++;
        System.out.printf("%d %d %s%n", r, p.wins, p.userName);
    }
}
```

Output

```
1 44 Solomon
2 42 Errol
2 42 Jason
4 41 Barry
4 41 Bernard
4 41 Garry
7 39 Stephen
```

Answer (score 0):

I cannot see the part where you are sorting your ArrayList.

```
Collections.sort(copyOfPlayerResultsList);
```

Before you for loop can do the job.

Comment: i have modified my question to include that sort prior to the ranking. `playerList.sort(Comparator.comparing(PickemResults::getPlayerWins, Comparator.reverseOrder()));`